# Error in exporting database

Tags: php, mysql, database, exec

I want to export my database using the PHP script I found [here](http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/mysql/13.html).

When I run the PHP script, a `sql` is created, but the `sql` is empty.

Besides, it also show this error in the browser :

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Export.php on line 12
There was a warning during the export of testing to ~/database/test1.sql
```

The line 12 is this line :

```
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
```

Besides, I changed the output path from the example,

```
$mysqlExportPath ='database/test1.sql';
```

How to solve this error? Or any others examples?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assigning a blank array in this line

```
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
```

So just put a variable inside this command.

```
$output=array();
exec($command,$output,$worked);
```

Comment: It's solve the `Strict Standards` error, but the warning is for exporting is still there. After that, the `sql` file is not created anymore.

Comment: @AnonyNewbie have you tried your command in command prompt. May be in that command any problem was present. Just try with it.